# Magmi - import error - csv correct?

Tags: magento, csv, import, magmi

Just cant seem to get magmi to import/work correctly. 
My CSV test file is only 27 lines including the header.

My header is as follows:

```
store, type_id, status, visibility, manage_stock, attribute_set, tax_class_id, weight, sku, name, price, cost, qty, description, short_description, manufacturer, vendor, color, size, product_id, upc, root_category, categories, is_in_stock, image, small_image, thumbnail, media_gallery
```

Example of the data:

```
admin, simple, Enabled, 4, 1, Default, Taxable Goods, 0.25, 400100433072, Daewon Song Gold/Purple, 21.99, 10, 1, Daewon Song Gold/ Purple, ear buds, ear buds, LOUD HAPPY HOUR, gold purple, 02-02-0009, 400100433072, Default Category, accessories/earbuds    1, /accessories/400100433072.jpg, /accessories/400100433072.jpg
```

Within Magento I added vendor,product_id, and upc as attributes and assigned them to the Default attribute set group.

When I do the import it
creates the very first item/product. (though where does one see custom attributes ?)
It does not create any of the Categories/sub categories. Including for the 1 product it does insert.
It creates an empty attribute per product line (IE 26)
        No  Yes     No  Global  No  No  No  (Magento Manage Attrib section)

Within magmi (0.7.2.2) I have set:
Attribute Set Importer
Import Report Mail Notifier 
Magmi Optimizer 
On the fly category creator/importer 
Image attributes processor
On the fly indexer
Magento 1.9.2.2

Update - 1-20-16

So far to get magneto Check Data to not error
I have changed type to _type, status from enabled to 1, tax_class_id from Taxable Goods to 2. (all contrary to what I've read)  This will pass the Check Data except for the data within the manufacturer-etc columns as they have not yet been created. Which of course is what magmi is for.

So on the magmi import 
It still errors out. Creating 26 blank attributes. (reload from backup to clear) I assume I still have my file structure incorrect. 
Reading it says "user-defined product attributes which magmi will import natively using a column name that has the attribute code" Therefor manufacturer, vendor, color, upc, product_id are in the header. These are all within the Default. Grouped as such. Appear on product record page.
That is all the attributes my test import has.
I am not creating new attribute_sets/groups (yet) 
So what is it that I am missing?

Anyone want to help me out? Please ...

Comment: Thanks for the clean up damek132.

Answer (score 0):

So I have made so headway.
I started experimenting. 
First if Magmi's Attribute Set Importer v0.0.2 was set ON - it would error and create 26 empty attributes no matter what I did.
Next it turns out you can not create and use custom attribute **product_id.** 
This also causes errors. I deleted that and changed it to manufacturer_id and it imports correctly.

Here is the header I have so far:

```
sku name    _attribute_set  root_category_id    weight  description short_description   categories  _type   status  visibility  manage_stock    tax_class_id    price   cost    qty manufacturer    vendor  color   upc manufacturer_id
```

Here is example data:

```
    400100433072    Daewon Song Gold and Purple Default 2   0.25    Daewon Song Gold and Purple ear buds    ear buds    accessories::1::0::1/earbuds::1::0::0   simple  1   4   1   2   21.99   10  1   LOUD    HAPPY HOUR  gold purple 400100433072    02-02-0009
```

Will just have to figure out how to deal with new attributes...